# Transfer passwords from firefox android to firefox desktop

Tags: password-management, android, firefox

I suddenly lost all passwords in firefox desktop. I have synced firefox on Android. All passwords remain on firefox android.

How to transfer all passwords from Android to Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Use Password Exporter. Export from Android and import into Desktop.

> This add-on allows you to export your saved passwords and disabled
> login hosts using XML or CSV files that can be imported later.
>
> Note: This add-on won't work in Firefox 57. It may eventually if the APIs to
> access passwords are implemented.

Source [Password Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/)

Android download: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/password-exporter/versions/?page=1#version-1.3.4

Desktop download: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can export the passwords and URL's with [an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/), but it cannot be used beyond Firefox v. 56 (it's legacy, not WebExt).

*Or*

2. From the Android Firefox profile in */data/data/org.mozilla.firefox*, copy logins.json and key3.db (decryption key) to the PC profile folder. **However**, [that requires */root* access...](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20190/path-where-firefox-mobile-addons-store-their-data) you **might** be able to view them from Firefox itself by using the URL *file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/logins.json* and */key3.db*.